# Implementation of 'My Location' button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, currentlocation

I am currently stuck while attempting to figure out how to add a button on my map that will redisplay a user's current location if they stray away from it on the map. At the moment I have the code written below that displays the user's current location.

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

   class GameViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate
   {

var lastUserLocation: MKUserLocation?





@IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()





func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.00775, 0.00775)

    let myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    self.Map.showsUserLocation = true
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()


}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()




}

@IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    print("click")
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

What I am unsure of, is what code to put inside of the @IBAction function that will allow the map to re-center to the user's current location if they stray from it while looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that you can call again `startUpdatingLocation` method of `CLLocationManager` on your `Button` action.

To get the the correct current location of user you need to access the `last` object from the `location` array in `didUpdateLocations` method.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //Access the last object from locations to get perfect current location
    if let location = locations.last {        
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.00775, 0.00775)        
        let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }               
    self.Map.showsUserLocation = true
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()                
}
```

Now simply call `startUpdatingLocation` on your button action.

```
@IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: I received an NSException when I attempted that implementation

Comment: @philhen27 Add the whole error in your question, if possible show the screenshot of error too

Comment: @philhen27 In storyboard you have set wrong action for your button with name location just remove connection with that and it will work for you.

Comment: @philhen27 In Storyboard check that you have set correct button action and remove the wrong one.